# c#: thread not working

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want the GIF image to be displayed whilst whilst the converter is processing. But the GIF image never shows displays and the converter process completes successfully whilst taking about 20 seconds, therefore the picture box is blank.
if I replace the converter process with MessageBox.Show, BOTH the Gif image and Message.Show works fine.

What do I need to do?

```
Thread th = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate                  
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("loading_gangnam.gif");                                 
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
});

th.Start(); 

//MessageBox.Show("This is main program");
Converted = converter.Convert(input.FullName, output);
```

Comment: don't access UI elements directly from threads. Take a look at either the backgroundworker or invoke. I would also put the long running thin in a thread.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing of the UI is done during the paint event, which only gets processed when your code finishes doing whatever thinking it is up to.

Additionally, your current code is broken. You should **never** manipulate UI controls (such as a `PictureBox`) from a worker thread. That causes "cross-thread operation detected" (or similar) exceptions.

Options:

- process part of the image, then let it paint, and schedule a timer or other event to continue the drawing momentarily
- do the work on a background thread on an **isolated** (non-UI) image, periodically making a **copy** of the current working image, and use `pictureBox1.Invoke(...)` to set the **copy** to the picture-box's content.

There is also an explicit way to let events be processed in a UI loop, but it is **really** bad practice, and I can't bring myself to even mention it by name.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the form controls from a different thread than the main UI thread.
You need to use Invoke().

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) for an example

Comment: this is very true, but isn't the main cause of the specific problem the OP is seeing (the UI not updating while editing). Definitely worth mentioning, though. But I'm not sure it really answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the threads backwards. You want your UI thread to display the GIF immediately, but the convert to run on the new thread. Should look like this:

```
Thread th = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate                  
{
    Converted = converter.Convert(input.FullName, output);
});
th.Start(); 

// should probably check pictureBox1.InvokeRequired for thread safety
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("loading_gangnam.gif");
```

Some further reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8xdz5c.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: @MamaduBascoBah - No prob. Would appreciate being marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to set the loading_gangnam.gif image:

```
public void newPicture(String pictureLocation)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<String>(newPicture), new object[] { pictureLocation });
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(pictureLocation);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

The project I'm working on has several threads all accessing the same form and this works for me!